# update drop down list items by selecting from other drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to to update the entries of a dropdown list when I change the selected item in the other dropdown list. I have three dropdown lists that represent days, month and year what I want is that when I update the month I want the days in the days dropdown list to change accordingly, e.g I select 4 (i.e april) in the month DDL I want the days DDL to show entries till 30. Here's what I've done but it has no effect

```
if (ddlmonth.SelectedIndex.Equals(6) || ddlmonth.SelectedIndex.Equals(6) || ddlmonth.SelectedIndex.Equals(9) || ddlmonth.SelectedIndex.Equals(11))
{

    for(int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
    {
        this.ddldate.Items.Add(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

I've enabled auto postback for all 3 DDL's still there's no effect. AND on Page_Load I've added the following years and months to be available for selection.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    for (int i = 1990; i < 2021; i++)
        this.ddlyear.Items.Add(i.ToString());

    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        this.ddlmonth.Items.Add(i.ToString());

}
```

Comment: How are you connecting dropdowns to event handlers?

Comment: Could you please clarify what does it mean "Here's what I've done but it has no effect" ? Also pleas note that you double first two expressions in the if(ddlmonth.SelectedIndex.Equals(6))

Comment: I wrote the first piece of code in the SelectedIndexChanged event of the month DDL so that when I change the index of the month DDL the items in the date DDL change accordingly i.e 30 days or 31 days etc for respective months  and the second piece of code is  written in the Page_Load event. Thanks for pointing out the double expressions.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You specifically mentioned April - there's a typo in your code, you're specifying June (6) twice and not April (4). That might be part of the problem.

Comment: thanks for the help people. I fixed it, had to add an item to the month DDL so that the selected item on page load is not 1 and it worked. Works for all the months now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some test code stuff

Aspx page code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Temp._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">Year
    <asp:DropDownList ID="_year" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="_year_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>Month
    <asp:DropDownList ID="_month" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="_month_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>Day
    <asp:DropDownList ID="_day" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="_day_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and aspx.cs file code were

```
namespace Temp
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                _year.DataSource = GetData.getYear();
                _year.DataTextField = "Year";
                _year.DataBind();
                _month.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select"));
                _month.DataBind();
                _day.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select"));
                _day.DataBind();
            }
        }
        protected void _year_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _month.Items.Clear();
            _month.DataSource = GetData.getMonth();
            _month.DataTextField = "MonthName";
            _month.DataValueField = "MonthId";
            _month.DataBind();
        }
        protected void _month_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _day.Items.Clear();
            _day.DataSource = GetData.getDays(_month.SelectedIndex+1,GetData.isLeapYear(Convert.ToInt32(_year.SelectedValue)));
            _day.DataTextField = "Day";
            _day.DataBind();
        }
        protected void _day_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //Use selected value of _month _year and _day here
        }
    }    
    public class GetData
    {
        public static List<day> getDays(int monthId,bool isLeapYear)
        {
            int maxLimit;
            if (monthId == 2)
            {
                if (isLeapYear) maxLimit = 29;
                else maxLimit = 28;
            }
            else if (monthId == 1 || monthId == 3 || monthId == 5 || monthId == 7 || monthId == 8 || monthId == 10 || monthId == 12)
                maxLimit = 31;
            else maxLimit = 30;
            List<day> days = new List<day>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= maxLimit; i++)
            {
                days.Add(new day { Day = i });
            }
            return days;

        }
        public static List<year> getYear()
        {
            //Set here min and max range of year 
            int minLimit = 1950;
            int maxLimit = DateTime.Now.Year;
            List<year> years = new List<year>();
            for (int i = minLimit; i <= maxLimit; i++)
            {
                //You can modify code for bind year dropdown 
                //respectively change in date or month
                /*if (isLeapYear)
                {
                    if(i%4==0)
                        years.Add(new year { Year = i });
                }
                else*/
                years.Add(new year { Year = i });
            }
            return years;
        }
        public static List<month> getMonth()
        {
            List<month> months=new List<month>();            
            months.Add(new month { MonthId = 1, MonthName = "Jan" });
            months.Add(new month { MonthId = 2, MonthName = "Frb" }); months.Add(new month { MonthId = 3, MonthName = "Mar" });
            months.Add(new month { MonthId = 4, MonthName = "Apr" }); months.Add(new month { MonthId = 5, MonthName = "May" });
            months.Add(new month { MonthId = 6, MonthName = "Jun" }); months.Add(new month { MonthId = 7, MonthName = "July" }); 
            months.Add(new month { MonthId = 8, MonthName = "Aug" });
            months.Add(new month { MonthId = 9, MonthName = "Sep" }); months.Add(new month { MonthId = 10, MonthName = "Oct" });
            months.Add(new month { MonthId = 11, MonthName = "Nov" });months.Add(new month { MonthId = 12, MonthName = "Dec" });
            return months;
        }
        internal static bool isLeapYear(int p)
        {
            if (p % 4 == 0)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }
    public class month
    {
        public string MonthName { get; set; }
        public int MonthId { get; set; }
    }
    public class day
    {
        public int Day { get; set; }
    }
    public class year
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hassan I'm suggesting you to use this kind of calender with javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you should add this functiom   void Index_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.onselectedindexchanged.aspx

Comment: I've already done this the code is written in this event but thanks anyway for answering.